# how to design multi-process program using redis in python

Tags: redis, thread-safety

I just started to use the redis cache in python. I read the tutorial but still feel confused about the concepts of "connectionpool", "connection" and etc..

I try to write a program which will be invoked multiple times in the console in different processes. They will all get and set the same shared in memory redis cache using same set of keys.

So to make it thread(process) safe, should I have one global connectionpool and get connections from the pool in different processes? Or should I have one global connection? What's the right way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of the program should spawn its own `ConnectionPool`. But this has nothing to do with thread safety. Whether or not your code is thread safe will depend on the type of operations you will be executing, and if you have multiple instances which may read and write concurrently, you need to look into using transactions, which are built into redis.